# Browsersync с php и чистым css

Tags: php, gulp

Второй день никак не могу справится с этими адскими инструментами. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Хочу сделать сайт с использованием php, и чтобы работал browser-sync. Да, в интернете полно всяких постов об этом, но там везде используются препроцессоры и все такое. Мне бы просто, чтобы browser-sync обновлял обычную php страницу с обычным css и js. Больше ничего не надо. Сам пробовал наверное раз 20 написать и переписать то, о чем говорится в этих мануалах - не получилось. Пожалуйста, напишите кто сможет gulpfile.js с ориентировкой на самого чайника из чайников. Есть open server, но там в корневой папке и находится сайт, без всяких app и т.д.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vW51JUVT66w